# Plotting Solution Curves in a Vector Field

Tags: plotting

I am having trouble trying to plot solution curves onto a vector field for this certain ODE. I have tried plotting with multiple different initial conditions/ different constants however I keep getting a blank graph.

```
eq1 = y'[x] == E^(-y[x])*Cos[y[x]];

sol1b = DSolve[eq1, y[x], x] /. C[1] -> c

   {{y[x] -> 
   InverseFunction[(1 - I) E^((1 + I) #1)
        Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 - I/2, 1, 3/2 - I/2, -E^(2 I #1)] &][
    c + x]}}



vf1 = VectorPlot[{1, E^(-y)*Cos[y]}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
   VectorScale -> {Large, 1/2, Automatic}];


p2b = Plot[
  Evaluate[Table[y[x] /. sol1b, {c, 0, 10, 1}]], {x, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> All]

Show[vf1, p2b]
```

This was my latest attempt. The vector field comes out great, it is my `p2b` plot that is causing problems. I'm guessing this has something to do with `InverseFunction`, but I really have no idea. I have tried lots of tricks from other posts but nothing seems to be working. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Would you want something like this?

```
vf1 = VectorPlot[{1, E^(-y)*Cos[y]}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  VectorScale -> {Large, 1/2, Automatic}, StreamPoints -> Coarse, 
  StreamStyle -> {Red, Thick}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(Internally, [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) is used to numerically compute the solution curves, a.k.a. stream lines.  This avoids the apparent branch-switching problems of the symbolic solution.)

Comment: Great answer (+1), from which I learned a lot.  However, it seems to me that `VectorPlot` has swept problems under the rug, so to speak.  Notice, for instance, the discontinuities at `y -> -1.5708` and near -5 and -8.  Incidentally, the core error in my answer was that I assumed `c` to be real.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks.  Yes, both `VectorPlot` and `StreamPlot` deal with equilibria by leaving white space.  You kinda have to get used to it, I guess.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you! This is a very helpful work-around that I never knew about.